# Cannot retrieve cell value within custom function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function MergeNames(sArrDep As String, rMergeRange As Range) As String
Dim sTeamMember As String, rNames As Range
Dim iCol As Integer, sMergeNames As String, iIndex As Integer
    If rMergeRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Set rNames = Range("NAMES")
    With rMergeRange
        If sArrDep = "A" Or sArrDep = "D" Then
            iCol = .Columns.Count
                For iIndex = 1 To iCol
                Debug.Print .Cells(1, iIndex)
                    If .Cells(1, iIndex).Value = sArrDep Then
                        sTeamMember = rNames.Cells(1, iCol)
                        If sMergeNames = "" Then
                            sMergeNames = sTeamMember
                        Else
                            sMergeNames = sMergeNames & "; " & sTeamMember
                        End If
                    End If
                Next iIndex
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    MergeNames = sMergeNames
End Function
```

> In the immediate window the cell value appears correctly:

? rmergerange.cells(1,iindex).value

A

However in the custom function the returned value = empty. When I run the same code as a subroutine then the content of the cell is correctly retrieved.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: What's the formula inside `Range("NAMES")`?

Comment: There is no formula in the that range. There is however a formula in the range rMergeRange. For instance the first cell contains the formula =IF($B6,IF(K$3<>"",INDEX(INDIRECT(K$3),$D6,$I$3),""),"") which equates to "A" as it is displayed in the worksheet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some sample data and how you're calling the UDF

Comment: I call the function as follows =MergeNames("A",K6:Y6). It seems that the function that generates the values in the rMergeRange is the culprit.

Comment: I found the error in the code sTeamMember = rNames.Cells(1, iCol) should be sTeamMember = rNames.Cells(1, iIndex). It calculates properly but is extremely slow probably due to the volatile INDIRECT.

Comment: Good. Indirect is costly but if you are using a UDF maybe you could calculate it inside the function

Comment: Ricardo thank you for your help and your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after removing the debug.print the code executes properly at a reasonable speed. Problem solved